# SQL CE Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

One of my database tables in SQL CE 3.5 has a primary key. I want to alter the column in the primary key to expand it from an nvarchar(7) to nvarchar(20).

Do I absolutely need to drop the primary key to achieve this?

How can I drop the primary key with a script if I do not know the name of the primary key?

The name is PK__sign_type__000000000000228E for example so it has been generated dynamically.

I have 200 or 300 of these databases on our clients machines and a generic script is necessary as they will all have different names for this primary key.

Answer (score 0):

First query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to see if the change is required:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Shippers' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Company Name'
```

Then get the constraint name from the table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS c INNER JOIN 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS u ON c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = u.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND      u.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
where c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'Shippers'
```

Then you can construct the primary key drop and alter the column.

Remember to give the primary key a proper name when you recreate.

Comment: OK, but this is required to be done programatically. I cannot create a SQL script for SQL CE which will do all of this correct?

Comment: Going to have to modify our software to be able to run some code it looks like. Just wanting to rule out the possibility of being able to do this with a SQL script.

Comment: Corect, you will have to use ado.net code to do this