# SQL CE drop primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

```
CREATE TABLE [selected_parameters]
([provider_id] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [parameter_id] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [parameter_name] NVARCHAR(100),
   [selected] BIT DEFAULT 0,
   [type] NVARCHAR(30)
);
ALTER TABLE [selected_parameters] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__selected_parameters__00000000000000BA] PRIMARY KEY ([provider_id], [parameter_id]);
```

How can I drop primary key in SQL CE 3.5 with out knowing it name ?

Comment: [Get the primary key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930338/sql-server-get-table-primary-key-using-sql-query), write dynamic SQL to drop the primary key (`ALTER TABLE <tablename> DROP CONSTRAINT <constraintname>`) and [execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) that dynamic SQL.

Comment: I can get primary key name by:

    `SELECT TOP(1) CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'selected_parameters'`

but in sql compact(ce) i can't declare variables to pass to execute, I can do that in program but I would like to do that only in sql ce

Comment: To prevent this situation in the first place, ALWAYS name your constraints yourself.

Comment: This question was already asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879338/sql-ce-dynamic-query). The conclusion was that you can only do this from code (see comments). And remember to ALWAYS name your constraints to prevent this situation in the future.

Comment: I always do that but some one else forget to do that and I have to clean up that mess. Ok, thanks I do that from code